# Capturing Date issue in my query

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have a function with a query in it that needs to save the current date to the MySQL DB,
however, when I place "CURDATE()" in my query none of the inputted date from the form will save to the DB at all. I am pretty sure I haven't got my syntax quite right.

Here's the function with the query to save everything to the DB

```
    function insert_campaign($userID, $campaign_name,$date_created) {
    $campaign_name = $this->real_escape_string($campaign_name);      
       $this->query("INSERT INTO campaigns (userid, campaign_name,date_created)" .
            " VALUES (" . $userID . ", '" . $campaign_name . "', CURDATE()");
}
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
 $this->query("INSERT INTO campaigns (userid, campaign_name,date_created)" .
            " VALUES (" . $userID . ", '" . $campaign_name . "', CURDATE()");
```

to

```
 $this->query("INSERT INTO campaigns (userid, campaign_name,date_created)" .
            " VALUES (" . $userID . ", '" . $campaign_name . "', CURDATE())");
```

Comment: Thanks so much ... the last bracket/parenthesis in the query just "looked" wrong so I didn't try it :-S ... Silly Me !

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the final closing parentheses after `CURDATE()`.

You can see why MySQL is giving you errors by checking the output of `mysql_query()`. It returns `false` when an error occurred.

When that happens you can use `mysql_error()` to determine why the error occurred.

Lastly, try to use PDO or mysqli; mysql_xx is going to be deprecated, so now is a good time to switch :)